# What is the correct notation to indicate that a function is taking a particular value for one of its parameters?

Tags: functions, notation

Consider a function which has both variables and parameters, such as
$$
y(x) = 3x^2 + ax + b,
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are the paramters (constants) for any one realisation, but $x$ is a variable. What is the correct notation to use to indicate the function with $a$, for example, taking a certain value?

Should it be something like the "evaluated at" symbol, like this:
$$
y(x)\rvert_{a=2} = 3x^2+2x+b
$$

or would it be written as an argument like this:
$$
y(x,a=2) = 3x^2+2x+b.
$$

Or is there another accepted way that I am not aware of?

Thank you.

Comment: Strictly speaking, $y=3x^2+ax+b$ is not a function. It simply expresses equality between the LHS and RHS. If however we write $y(x)=3x^2+ax+b$, then we are dealing with a function. The function is called $y$, and when it is evaluated at the point $x$, you get $3x^2+ax+b$. If you write $y(x)=3x^2+ax+b$, then it is assumed that $a$ and $b$ are constants. If the value of $a$ is variable, then you are dealing with a function that takes two arguments: $y(x,a)=3x^2+ax+b$. If both $a$ and $b$ are variable, then it is $y(x,a,b)=3x^2+ax+b$.

Comment: I've gone with the first option ("evaluated at") most often. It's clean and unambiguous in my opinion.

Comment: @Joe Yes I agree, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I’ll tangentially comment that (in my opinion) notation is never “correct” or “incorrect” as much as it is *helpful* and *well-defined* or *confusing* and *misleading*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you plan on specifying the parameter $a$, it might be best to choose beforehand a notation that reflects that intention. For example, either of the notational choices $y(x,a)=3x^2+ax+b$ or $y_a(x)=3x^2+ax+b$ makes it easy to show what you want to show. (And similar notational choices can be used for $b$, with or without $a$.)

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like you agree there is nothing wrong with my second option. Do you think the first one is okay too? I typically have only seen that notation when dealing wth derivatives.

Comment: I wouldn't write $y(x,a=2)$—that seems cumbersome to me. I would define $y(x,a) = ...$, and then simply write $y(x,2)$. The first notation is okay, but I still recommend the options in my answer.